# Assertion fails after modifying another array in Dafny

Tags: dafny

I ran into a weird problem in Dafny. I tried to extract it as much as possible here: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/F7sK

The thing is, after the modification of **truthAssignment**, **stack.valid** fails even if **stack.valid** doesn't know about **truthAssignment**.

```
assert stack.valid();
truthAssignment[variable] := 1;
assert stack.valid();  // assertion violation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Dafny fails to verify the assertion `assert stack.valid();` is the last conjunct in the body of `valid()`:

```
(forall c :: c in contents ==>
  exists i,j :: 0 <= i < stack.Length 
             && 0 <= j < |stack[i]| 
             && stack[i][j] == c)
```

It has the form `forall ... exists ...`, and proving such a condition to be invariant is difficult for the verifier. Once you have figured out that this is the part of `valid()` that the verifier cannot prove (which you can do by, for example, manually inlining the definition of `valid()` in place of your assertion), then the solution is to give the verifier some assistance.

When the verifier--or a human, for that matter--tries to prove something for the form `forall c :: P(c)`, then it makes up an arbitrary `c` and then tries to prove the "`P(c)`" for it. (Logicians call this rule "universal introduction".) Easy. Then, to prove something of the form `exists i,j :: Q(i,j)`, the verifier looks for a witness to the "`Q(i,j)`". (This is known as "existential introduction".) Here, the verifier is not particularly creative and often needs help. Sometimes, you have to figure out some `i` and `j` yourself and then assert `Q(i,j)`. Other times, it suffices to just mention some component of the needed `Q(i,j)` and the verifier will then figure out the rest. Exactly what to do can be a trial-and-error process.

What makes James's remedy above work is the fact that it mentions `stack.stack[..]` after the update `truthAssignment[variable] := 1;`. This tickles the verifier in a way that lets it see the light. Just writing the trivially proved assertion:

```
assert 0 <= |stack.stack[..]|;  // mentioning stack.stack[..] helps the verifier in the next line
```

after the update also works in this case.

Rustan

Comment: But why is Dafny proofing again the assertion if stack.valid is not related with truthAssignment?

Comment: Because the assertion implicitly mentions the heap and your assignment is changing the heap.

Answer (score 1):

The following verifies for me:

```
assert stack.valid();
ghost var old_stack := stack.stack[..];
truthAssignment[variable] := 1;
assert stack.stack[..] == old_stack;
assert stack.valid();
```

I don't really understand why this works, but it falls under the general category of "extentional equality for sequences is hard for Dafny".

Comment: but why modifying one would impact the other? I came across multiple times on problems of equality between sequences, but not like this one...

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me. we'd have to ask Rustan.